# Simple Business Card Administration - Access Violation When Writing [Visual Studio 2015]

Tags: c, arrays, structure, access-violation

I currently try to program a simple Business Card Administrator (very very simple). There I have multiple functions(add card, edit card, ...).
I currently finished the first function addCard but when I run the program and call the function, I get an error (Access violation when writing) when I call the first scanf function of my addCard function. So here is my code:

main.c:

```
#include "card.h"

int main() {

int action = 0;
int index = 1;
Card *card[50];
while (action != 5)
{
    action = menu(action);
    printf("Number: %i", action);
    switch (action) {
    case 1: addCard(*card, index); index++;  return 0;
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

card.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
}Date;

typedef struct
{
Date birthday;
char name[20];
char firstName[20];
char address[80];
char phonenumber[20];
 }Card;

int menu(int action);
void addCard(Card *acard, int aindex);
```

card.c:

```
#include "card.h"
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#pragma warning(disable:4700)

int menu(int action) {

printf("Menu: \n");
printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
printf("1 -- Add Card\n");
printf("2 -- Edit/Update Card\n");
printf("3 -- Show Card\n");
printf("4 -- Delete Card\n");
printf("5 -- Exit\n");
printf("Action (1-4): \n");
printf("--------------------------------------------\n");
scanf(" %i", &action);
return action;
}

void addCard(Card *acard, int aindex) {

system("cls");
printf("Add new Card\n");
printf("Name: ");
scanf(" %s",  &acard[aindex].name);    //Access Violation when Writing Exception Error 
printf("First Name: ");
scanf(" %s", &acard[aindex].firstName);
printf("Adress: ");
scanf(" %s", &acard[aindex].address);
printf("Phone-Number: ");
scanf(" %s", &acard[aindex].phonenumber);
Date date;
printf("Date of birth: (dd-mm-yyyy): ");
scanf(" %i-%i-%i", &date.day, &date.month, &date.year);
acard[aindex].birthday = date;

}
```

Comment: Why are you disabling warning C4700 with #pragma ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `card` array. It's an array of (unintialized) pointers to `Card`. Then when you call `addCard` using `*card`, that's the same as calling it with `card[0]` which means you pass an uninitialized pointer to the `addCard` function, which uses that pointer as an array. This leads to *undefined behavior* and bad things happening.

The simple solution? Don't declare `card` as an array of pointers, but as an array of structures. I.e.

```
Card card[50];
```

Then pass plain `card` to the `addCard` function (using an array like that will make it decay to a pointer to the first element, `card == &card[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

`Card *card[50];` are 50 pointers with type `Card*`.

```
Card  card[50];
addCard( &(card[0]), index);
```